# AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'sleep'

Tags: python, attributes

I am fairly new to Python (and programming in general), so please excuse my lack of knowledge or understanding to something you may find obvious. I'm not stupid though, so hopefully I should be able to work it out.

I am making a small text-based survival game, and I have encountered an issue which I cannot seem to solve, which is the:

> AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'sleep'

In the console when I try and run my program.

```
import time , sys , random , shelve
# /gather command
if '/gather' in Input and command_state == True:
    if 'wood' in Input:
        print('Collecting wood...')
        if tool != "Axe": 
            time.sleep(random.randrange(5 , 10))
            print("Test")
        else:
            time.sleep(random.randrange(5 , 10))
            print("Test")
```

I really don't understand what is causing this and after looking through the advice given on similar topics I have found no solution. Any help would be appreciated!

If you'd like me to put up the whole script, please just ask. I have only put up the block of code that was causing the issue (because none of the other code seemed to affect anything here).

Comment: You are overwriting the module `time` by a variable with the same name.

Comment: Thank you for the help! I realised in the setup I had a variable called 'time', which was a redundant variable so I have removed it. Thanks again!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As commented above you are overwriting the `time` module by making a variable named time. Simply rename the `time` variable!

Comment: Thank you for the help! I realised in the setup I had a variable called 'time', which was a redundant variable so I have removed it. Thanks again!